# rewrite working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm uploading my website on my server. The rewrite rules above were working on my localhost. URL "mywebsite.com/about" served me "mywebsite.com/about.php". But something weird happens.

My htaccess file has got the right autorizations, I Know that because the other rules (deflate for exemple) are working correctly.

mod_rewrite is on, I know that because some of my rules are working. However, not everything : when typing "mywebsite.com/about" or "mywebsite.com/about.php", I get redirected to "mywebsite.com/about", but it displays a 404 error.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /includes/404.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +MultiViews
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /en [L]
    ### to hide '.php' extensions
    # Unless directory, remove trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
###
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I would really apreciate help on finding where I go wrong!

**EDIT:**

The page I'm trying to access is actually "mywebsite.com/en/about.php" by the URL "mywebsite.com/en/about"

**EDIT 2:**

I left nothing but this line on my .htaccess :

```
# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

What it does is : strictly nothing... If I understand it well, this is the part that should redirect URL with no extensions to the .php version of it. When I go to mywebsite.com/en/about , i get a 404.

**EDIT 3:**

Using this other script gives the same result : rewriting the URL in "mywebsite.com/en/about" is working, but it doesn't redirect to the .php version.

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]


# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Are you sure your server is reading the htaccess file? You could test it by briefly adding smth invalid to the file - if the server reads it it will throw a 500 error on everything.

Comment: Already did, got an error 500...

Comment: Sorry to ask but better to check - you have definitely uploaded the 404 file to the expected path in your webroot - `/about.php` ?

Comment: Yep, double checked ! the about page (like the others) works perfectly when accessing to it with "about.php" and no .htaccess file

Comment: Do you need Multiviews?

Comment: no, just supress lines 2 to 4, no change.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Is `en/` a real directory?

Comment: it is located in the root folder of the website, en/ is a real directory.

Comment: Try this single rule: `RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]` from root

Comment: This gives me a 404 for all the previous pages, and also for my indexes (mywebsite.com/en/). This indexes pages were working fine previously.